# TFS GIT getting full Error TF30042. tbl_content is full

Tags: sql-server, git, tfs

We are running our project in TFS using Git. Recently it started giving Error

> TF30042: The database is full. Contact your Team Foundation Server
>   administrator. Server: ATSS-P-AAI\SqlExpress01, Error: 1105, Message:
>   'Could not allocate space for object
>   'dbo.tbl_Content'.'PK_tbl_Content' in database 'Tfs_DefaultCollection'
>   because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting
>   unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional
>   files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in
>   the filegroup.

I have checked and found that the tbl_content itself has occupied around 9.5GB of space while the total DB size is 10GB. One of my teammate had mistakenly checked in a repository with huge binary files before this happened. He has deleted the repository but seems like the tbl_content is still having same space.

I have tried setting **autogrowth** as well, but nothing seems to be working. We are now not able to use it anymore.

Any solutions are suggested.

Comment: Hi @PatrickLu-MSFT, we had actually moved to Azure.We already knew that the DB Size for Express is limited to 10GB, but we were not able to figure the abnormal growth as our code base is around 1.1GB. I wanted to get it cleaned by deleting the huge files, but could not succeed.

Comment: Hi @undefined Good to know. Not only the source code but also build artifacts/ work item /test result will also take place of your collection database.  It's equally possible that those things were exceeding limits for database. After you clean the database, better to restart the whole TFS sever/ background service  and database. This may do the trick.  Certainly, move your project to Cloud (Azure DevOps Service) is also a good solution. You could also use more and latest feature at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restricted File Growth in **autogrowth** will not work  in your situation. Since the 10GB limitation is from SQL Express s Daniel mentioned.

> *SQL Server Express: Limitations of the free version of SQL Server*
>
> The most important limitation is that **SQL Server Express does not
>   support databases larger than 10 GB**. This will prevent you from
>   growing your database to be large.

What you can do at present:

1. Clean the drive to free up space. Delete transaction logs, look for extraneous test case attachments, build drops checked into source that sort of thing.
2. Restore your prior back-up database
3. Use SQL Server Standard instead

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're using SQL Express. SQL Express is limited to databases of up to 10 GB.

The easy answer here is that you should upgrade your SQL edition. It may be possible to remove data from the database, but doing so without explicit instructions from Microsoft is not recommended.